# HTML to Google Sites

Tags: html, dreamweaver, google-sites

I have a website that is a bunch of standard HTML4 files. It has a Dreamweaver template file but each file has the template already put into it.

Is there an easier way to convert a website from HTML files to Google Sites than to copy the source code of each file and create a page on Google Sites with that source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this [FAQ](http://www.steegle.com/websites/google-sites-howtos/googlesites-frequentlyaskedquestionsfaq#TOC-Can-I-upload-my-own-site-made-in-iW) can be helpful to understand what Google Sites exactly is, what it can and what it can't.

Unfortunately Google Sites isn't flexible and powerful as it's wanted.

Depending of your needs you could try to use Blogger or [Google App Enginge](http://code.google.com/intl/ru/appengine/). You could search simple CMS for GAE and try to export your Dreamweaver project to GAE hosting.

If it will help you, please inform me. I think it's interesting to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a local working copy of a  css/java website.... all you need to do is copy the website folder with all the website files to a google drive folder that is shared publicly. Then get the hosting link for your websites index.html from the detail description of the index.html file that is in the folder that is now on google drive. Open your google site and add a full page iframe using the hosting link to your website index.html file as its source.

the local website you created is now live on google sites as your website

Comment: Hmm.. it looks like hosting was removed from Google Drive according to [this link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/A-fpkPuNhj8).

Answer (score 0):

If Google sites is still like it was about two years ago when I used it, that is the only way. Its sad, but Google sites is not supposed to be for doing anything past basic html.